# having trouble using functions to break up my code

Tags: python, function, void

I have a monthly budget code that shows the user if they are over/under the budget for a certain month. I am having trouble breaking the code up into def functions. here is what I have

```
print("""\
This program uses a for loop to monitor your budget.
The program will prompt you to enter your budget, and amount spent
for a certain month and calculate if your were under or over budget.
You will have the option of choosing how many months you would like to
monitor.\n""")


AmountSpent = 0
Budget = 0


numMonths = int(input("Enter the number of months you would like to monitor:"))
while numMonths<0:
    print("\nNegative value detected!")
    numMonths = int(input("Enter the number of months you would like to monitor"))
for month in range(1,numMonths+1):
    print("\n=====================================")
    AmountBudgeted = float(input(f"Enter amount budgeted for month {month}:"))
    while AmountBudgeted<0:
         print("Negative value detected!")
         AmountBudgeted = float(input(f"Enter amount budgeted for month {month}:"))
    AmountSpent = float(input(f"Enter amount spent for month {month}:"))
    while AmountSpent<0:
         print("Negative value detected!")
         AmountSpent = float(input(f"Enter amount spent for month {month}:"))
    if AmountSpent <= AmountBudgeted:
        underB = AmountBudgeted - AmountSpent
        print(f"Good Job! You are under budget by {underB}")
    else:
        overB = AmountSpent - AmountBudgeted
        print(f"Oops! You're over budget by {overB}")
    if month == "1":
       print(f'your budget is {AmountBudgeted}.')
```

Can anyone help me break this code up into functions using "def" and other functions like "Describeprogram()" and "GetMonths()" ?

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the user interaction like

```
def get_nb_months():
    value = int(input("Enter the number of months you would like to monitor:"))
    while value < 0:
        print("Negative value detected!")
        value = int(input("Enter the number of months you would like to monitor"))
    return value
```

But then you notice that they're quite the same methods, so you can generalize:

```
def get_amount(msg, numeric_type):
    value = numeric_type(input(msg))
    while value < 0:
        print("Negative value detected!")
        value = numeric_type(input(msg))
    return value

def summary(spent, budget):
    diff = abs(budget - spent)
    if spent <= budget:
        print(f"Good Job! You are under budget by {diff}")
    else:
        print(f"Oops! You're over budget by {diff}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    numMonths = get_amount("Enter the number of months you would like to monitor:", int)
    for month in range(1, numMonths + 1):
        print("\n=====================================")
        amount_budgeted = get_amount(f"Enter amount budgeted for month {month}:", float)
        amount_spent = get_amount(f"Enter amount spent for month {month}:", float)
        summary(amount_spent, amount_budgeted)
```

Comment: Is there any way i can implement the functions DescribeProgram() GetMonths() analyzeBudget() and at the end use main() ?

Comment: @Pillis You can maybe try by yourself now no ? I don't know what you want to put behind these method names